# JavaScript Multiple Images Per Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to multiple layout image in per slider with same effect. The issues is here every slider has with background image. I don't want one image on that. what I am trying to fix that every slider I want to be three grid images.

[Like the Screenshot Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLWXZ.jpg)

[Here is Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/rabbi598/pen/QrwbmN)

Here is the function I call how add the image in background during sliding. Hope I will get my solution from here.

```
layout() {
        this.DOM.el.classList.add('uncover');
        let inner = '';
        inner += `<div class="uncover__img" style='background-image: ${this.DOM.el.style.backgroundImage}'></div>
        <div class="uncover__slices uncover__slices--${this.options.orientation}">`;

        for (let i = 0; i <= this.options.slicesTotal - 1; ++i) {
            inner += `<div class="uncover__slice" style="color:${this.options.slicesColor}"></div>`;
        }
        inner += `</div>`;
        this.DOM.el.innerHTML = inner;
        this.DOM.img = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.uncover__img');
        this.DOM.slices = Array.from(this.DOM.el.querySelectorAll('.uncover__slice'));
        this.slicesTotal = this.DOM.slices.length;
    }
```

Thanks in 
advance.